# Как правильно примонтировать диск данными в /home

Tags: linux

У меня вот возникла такая проблема... Установил себе на ноут Ubuntu 12.04.1. Винт разделен на 3 раздела (swap-sda1, /-sda2 и sda3). Так вот, хочу щас раздел sda3 смонтировать в /home, чтоб не терять пользовательские настройки после переустановки системы. Возник вопрос, не сломаю ли я систему прописав монтирование этого раздела в /etc/fstab. И не потеряю ли пользовательские данные после первой же перегрузки системы? Если так, то как правильно мне все сделать?

Comment: @alexusnet, если Вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то `/home` сейчас в `/dev/sda2` и планируется разместить его в `/dev/sda3`. Тогда сперва нужно данные переместить в `/dev/sda3`:

`mkdir /mnt/home`
`mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/home`

`\#` далее переместить любым доступным методом все файлы (не забыть про скрытые) из `/home`

в `/mnt/home`

`umount /dev/sda3`

правка `/etc/fstab`

`\#` никаких ребутов

`mount -a`

`\#` всё, теперь `df -h` и видим что надо

Comment: спасибо ))))

Comment: не забыть выгнать пользователей, чтобы /home не был занят и самому под root заходить, а не через sudo

Answer (score 1):

Я этим мануалом пользовался. Все получилось.
[Move /home to it’s own partition](http://embraceubuntu.com/2006/01/29/move-home-to-its-own-partition/).

Answer (score 1):

Не стоит монтировать разделы в fstab по конкретному имени девайса (/dev/sda3), монтируйте разделы по UUID, его можно выяснить командой sudo blkid.

Пример вывода blkid:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="4b9fb3d5-f1cd-47b8-af0c-3b14fd6ef4ad" TYPE="ext4"/dev/sda2: UUID="A4E0DDE0E0DDB8AE" TYPE="ntfs"/dev/sda4: UUID="d83a7677-8679-49e5-a4cb-4ff63801505d" TYPE="ext4"
```

Далее строка из /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=d83a7677-8679-49e5-a4cb-4ff63801505d /home ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Comment: а что делать, если переезжаешь на новый комп?

Comment: то же самое и делаешь! UUID сменится автоматически, его выясняешь так же, как описано выше. Имя девайса может смениться при подключении, например, съемного жесткого диска, т.е. с sda3 на sda4. Именно по этой причине лучше всего монтировать по UUID

Comment: но при подключении девайса sda3 никогда не станет sda4..

Comment: на запущеной системе нет...